# How to modify the buffer-list using modify-frame-parameters

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to create a function that modifies a frame's buffer-list by replacing it with the buffer listing of tabs from a Tabbar group displayed on the same frame.

This is the snippet that returns a listing of tabs from the Tabbar group displayed on the selected frame:

```
(mapcar (lambda (tab)
  (buffer-name (tabbar-tab-value tab)))
    (tabbar-tabs (tabbar-current-tabset t)))
```

The following function returns `nil` instead of the desired Modified Buffer List.   Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
(defun new-buffer-list ()
(interactive)
  (message "Original Buffer List:  %s" (frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'buffer-list))
  (setq new-list
    (mapcar (lambda (tab)
      (buffer-name (tabbar-tab-value tab)))
        (tabbar-tabs (tabbar-current-tabset t))))

  (modify-frame-parameters (selected-frame) (list (cons 'buffer-list new-list)))
  (message "The variable \"new-list\":  %s" new-list)
  (message "Modified Buffer List:  %s" (frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'buffer-list)))
```

Comment: My guess is that buffer-list is a variable used and modified by emacs internals, so trying to modify it won't have the results you expect.  You can verify that once you set it to nil, the list is repopulated as soon as you change buffers or windows.  If you know of an example of code that successfully change this frame parameter, I would be very interested in a pointer to it.

Comment: I am configuring a modified version of `frame-bufs.el` to play nice with Tabbar.  When switching into `frame-bufs-mode` there is an optional frame initialization that associates the buffer in each frame with focus:  `(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (window-buffer x)) (window-list frame 'no-minibuf))`.  I would like to use my `new-list` instead, so that all open tabs get associated.  If there were a way to somehow modify the format of my `new-list` to be just like `(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (window-buffer x)) (window-list frame 'no-minibuf))`, then that would do the trick.

Comment: All of the following examples have the same general format, which somehow differs from my `new-list` (but I do not know why or how to fix it):  `(frame-parameter frame 'buffer-list)` and `(frame-parameter frame 'buried-buffer-list)` and `(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (window-buffer x)) (window-list frame 'no-minibuf))`.

Comment: `message` returns the string message, never `nil`

Comment: `(frame-parameter 'nil 'buffer-list)` returns a list of buffers, not their names; you might want to replace `(lambda (tab) (buffer-name (tabbar-tab-value tab)))` with `'tabbar-tab-value`.

Comment: @sds -- Thank you very much -- that did indeed put me back on the right track, and it also works in the sample function in the question above.  I need to do a little work distributing the desired result across all frames when enabling `frame-bufs-mode`, but you got me past the initial stumbling block.  Greatly appreciated !!!  :)

Comment: you are welcome, I added an answer based on the comment

Comment: @juanleon:  You are correct with respect to the buffer-list evolving after it has been set to something specific.  Using the solution of `sds`, I am taking a read of the existing tabbar tabs and then setting that result equal to a variable.  Thereafter, I am using that same defined variable to `temporarily` modify the buffer-list for the purposes of setting it equal to `frame-bufs-buffer-list`.  In this regard, the tab groupings previously displayed on each frame without `frame-bufs-mode` remain the same after that mode is activated -- once activated, tabs are adjusted on-the-fly in any frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(frame-parameter 'nil 'buffer-list)
```

returns a list of **buffers**, not their **names**; thus you might want to replace

```
(lambda (tab) (buffer-name (tabbar-tab-value tab)))
```

with `'tabbar-tab-value`